# Excel - having the dropbox allow multiple clicks

Tags: excel, excel-2010

On Windows Excel 2010 I have made a drop list,this list is on a second sheet. My first sheet can pick up the list on the second sheet and select one of the options on that list. But how do i get it to allow multiple options from the same list is that possible ?

Thank you for your time.

Update: the list is numbers and letters A34243 ,B234234, 1231, 222 ,2 ,1 
I have the dropdown list set up through data validation. and while I can select any options from the list but i can only select one. I am looking for a multiple selection option. if there is way to possible do it.

Comment: Why the negative? if this cannot be done just say, I see a few excel questions here.

Comment: You need more details here. ie: What does your data look like, what kind of drop list, how does your first sheet pick up one of the options, what do you mean by multiple options, etc etc

Comment: are you serious ? well okay there really isn't much to it.

Comment: What do you mean by "Multiple Selection"? You can't select multiple items through the data validation dropdown list. What is the result you want. ie: do you want the data validation cell to show "THING 1 - THING 2 - THING 3", or do you want each item to be presented in its own dropdown? What are you using the dropdown list for? Visual display, or do other cells refer to it.

Comment: thing 1 - thing 2 - thing 3, visual display. otherwise i will just copy it and add more columns. which sounds like i may have to do anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a ListBox instead of a ComboBox if you want to allow multiple selections.

This combined with the option list style creates a list of checkboxes.

Alternatively, you can write the VBA code to do things when a dropdown list value is selected. This means you can set a value if they pick something, and then set another value if they pick something else, but you will have to write the code to handle those situations.

Here is an example using a Listbox:

[image: ListBox1]

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()

Range("O15").Value = vbNullString
Dim Item
For Item = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox1.Selected(Item) Then 
        Range("O15").Value = Range("O15").Value & ListBox1.List(Item) & ","
    End If
Next Item
'Just to remove the last coma in our list
'There are better ways to display the selection, but this is just one
If Range("O15") <> vbNullString And Len(Range("O15")) > 1 Then
    Range("O15") = Left(Range("O15"), Len(Range("O15")) - 1)
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you preciously what i am looking for. Just needed to use a ListBox